# Polymorphism - Main activity - Reference null object

Tags: java, android

I implemented polymorphism using interface for calling a function of main activity but during calling or passing a reference, it becomes null. Please help me, what do I do?

**+** I create an object of second class in onCreate method of main activity:

```
public class PlayerAudioActivity extends Activity implements Listenercalling{

      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
      {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_player_audio);
          MyReceiver mReciever = new MyReceiver();
          mReciever.setMyInterface(PlayerAudioActivity.this);
      }

     public void getplay()
     {
         Log.d("yeppppppppppppppppp", "jsdhijdiowejd");
         if(mp.isPlaying())
            { 
                if(mp!=null)
                {
                    mp.pause();
                    btnplay.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_play);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if(mp!=null)
                {
                    mp.start();
                    btnplay.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_pause);
                }

            }


     }
}
```

**+** my interface:

```
package com.Audio.audioplayer;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.SeekBar;

public interface Listenercalling {
     public void getplay();
}
```

**+** my second class:

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver implements  Listenercalling{
    private Listenercalling ls;
    private static final String TAG = "waaaawoooooooooOOOOOOjnjkhdfku";
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //btnplay=(ImageButton)btnplay;
         final String action=intent.getAction();
         if(action=="btnplay")
         {

             getplay();
             Log.d(TAG, ""+action);

         }
}
public void setMyInterface(PlayerAudioActivity pl)
    {
        Log.d("wawwwooo"+pl, "lfkero");
        ls=pl;


    }
@Override
public void getplay() {
        Log.d("wawwwooo", "getplayreciever calling");
        ls=new PlayerAudioActivity();   
        ls.getplay();   
    }
}
```

**+** error:

```
04-25 18:08:25.805: E/AndroidRuntime(30100): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-25 18:08:25.805: E/AndroidRuntime(30100): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.Audio.audioplayer.MyReceiver: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-25 18:08:25.805: E/AndroidRuntime(30100):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2520)
04-25 18:08:25.805: E/AndroidRuntime(30100):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:156)
04-25 18:08:25.805: E/AndroidRuntime(30100):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1416)
04-25 18:08:25.805: E/AndroidRuntime(30100):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-25 18:08:25.805: E/AndroidRuntime(30100):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
04-25 18:08:25.805: E/AndroidRuntime(30100):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
04-25 18:08:25.805: E/AndroidRuntime(30100):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-25 18:08:25.805: E/AndroidRuntime(30100):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-25 18:08:25.805: E/AndroidRuntime(30100):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
04-25 18:08:25.805: E/AndroidRuntime(30100):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
04-25 18:08:25.805: E/AndroidRuntime(30100):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-25 18:08:25.805: E/AndroidRuntime(30100): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-25 18:08:25.805: E/AndroidRuntime(30100):    at com.Audio.audioplayer.PlayerAudioActivity.getplay(PlayerAudioActivity.java:414)
04-25 18:08:25.805: E/AndroidRuntime(30100):    at com.Audio.audioplayer.MyReceiver.getplay(MyReceiver.java:138)
04-25 18:08:25.805: E/AndroidRuntime(30100):    at com.Audio.audioplayer.MyReceiver.onReceive(MyReceiver.java:28)
04-25 18:08:25.805: E/AndroidRuntime(30100):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2513)
04-25 18:08:25.805: E/AndroidRuntime(30100):    ... 10 more
```

Comment: at which line the error occurs. Please specify more details

Comment: What is becoming null, and where? Pls specify

Comment: here i passing reference to myreciever class mReciever.setMyInterface(PlayerAudioActivity.this); and then  Myreciever class i casting  ls=pl; and then in onrecieve to call getplay method of my reciever and then in getplay method i call getplay method of main class  but i dont know why they become a null    means when they reach getplay of method its have null in mediaplayer object

Comment: when clicking on button for to play

Answer (score 0):

At a glance, I see two problems with the code.

1. the variable `mp` is not a member variable or is not passed through to your `getPlay`() method;
2. the way you've written the code doesn't really make sense. You check if `mp.isPlaying()` and then you check if it's different from `null`. Better would be.

   ```
   public void getPlay() {
       if (mp != null) {
           if (mp.isPlaying() {
               mp.pause();
               btnplay.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_play);
           } else {
               mp.start();
               btnplay.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_pause);
           } 
       } 
   }
   ```

As far as I can see, the NullPointerException may be gone, but I don't think it'll work just yet, as you still need to initialize your `mp` variable.